# PowerShell log filter function buffering output

Tags: powershell, logging, filter, log4cplus, write-host

My application uses log4cplus for logging.

When I launch it in CMD or PowerShell, logging is ok, line by line.

I decided to add small filtering function in PS, to make the output colorful.

```
# Simplified version
function ColoredOutput
{
    process { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Yellow }
}
```

After this I launch the app as following:

```
myapp.exe | ColoredOutput
```

The problem is that now I get log messages in chunks for about several messages at a time, not line by line. I cannot understand what triggers the actual output.

Looks to me like some buffering of the output. Any ideas?

**UPD:** The problem seems to be related to some messages logged using simple std::cout in C++ instead of the logger.

**UPD2:** I start thinking that it's actually C++ that triggers the output. As you can see from the image below, the last message is from std::cout, all the previous - from log4cplus. 
[image: example output]

Comment: I can't reproduce that (V4, using ping -t).

Comment: Can you show us what some of the output looks like? I wonder what stream the program is using... perhaps you need to put all to the standard output.

Comment: @Matt: See UPD2 in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. As it appeared, indeed it was log4cplus, which was buffering.
Adding the following to the config helps:

```
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.ImmediateFlush=true
```

Thanks to the interested, sorry for bothering.